# Qt virtualkeyboard assertion error in 5.15.2 vs 5.12.3

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.12, qt5.15

I recently updated my Qt version from `5.12.3` to `5.15.2`. I rebuilt an application that uses a qt virtualkeyboard in QML using `InputPanel {}`. The virtual keyboard is defined in main as `qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));`. Everything works in release mode but when I run in debug mode I get the following application output from qt creator:

```
Program: C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt5Cored.dll
Module: 5.15.2
File: qvirtualkeyboardinputcontext_p.cpp
Line: 221

ASSERT: "!this->inputPanel" in file qvirtualkeyboardinputcontext_p.cpp, line 221
```

I inspected  the source file on [Github for 5.15.2](https://github.com/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/blob/7b90415c58dd02c682a9ba317f273d7b3398ff88/src/virtualkeyboard/qvirtualkeyboardinputcontext_p.cpp) and the line number points to method `void QVirtualKeyboardInputContextPrivate::registerInputPanel(QObject *inputPanel)` with `Q_ASSERT(!this->inputPanel);`. I wanted to compare this method with [Github for 5.12.3](https://github.com/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard/blob/152f6935f050e83363f1b4f40c40af7f64ca5df9/src/virtualkeyboard/qvirtualkeyboardinputcontext_p.cpp) but it looks like this method was added after `5.12.3` hence why I didn't see the error before.

Now, my understanding is that `Q_ASSERT(bool)` will call `qFatal()` when the flag is false. If `inputPanel` is of type `QObject*` should the Q_ASSERT be `Q_ASSERT(this->inputPanel)`? The Q_ASSERT should only trigger when the pointer is a nullptr. Or maybe I'm just confused?

Comment: Since you've a commercial license I would ask TQtC for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was already an existing bug report on Qt's bug tracker. Previously I only searched by virtualkeyboard and not InputPanel. The bug report is [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90809). BTW, it looks like this is only an issue in debug mode and a workaround is to click the ignore button several times to continue in debug mode.

Edit: Qt responded that this assert check is to make sure that there is only 1 `InputPanel` component in the whole application. So, I am not sure how `InputPanel` is suppose to work when we have multiple dynamic views in a MVVM architecture design where each view has it's own self contained `InputPanel`.

Edit2: Updating per my last edit comment. I put the InputPanel at the main qml file that controls the StackView and the views that are dynamically loaded are able to use the same InputPanel.